# Heroku: Cannot run more than 2 Free size dynos

Tags: python, heroku

I keep running into this error when I try to run a `clock` process.

Here is my Procfile

```
web: gunicorn app:app --log-level debug
worker: python worker.py
clock: python clock.py
```

When I list out my dynos `heroku ps` I get:

```
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 943h 3m (94%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

=== web (Free): gunicorn app:app --log-level debug (1)
web.1: up 2017/09/26 11:34:20 -0400 (~ 3m ago)

=== worker (Free): python worker.py (1)
worker.1: up 2017/09/26 11:34:18 -0400 (~ 3m ago)
```

Then when I go to run `heroku ps:scale clock=1`

It comes back as `Cannot run more than 2 Free size dynos`

I have tried restarting stopping all the dyno's and then scaling them again:

```
(env) spitfiredd@spitfiredd ~/Documents/schedule $ heroku ps:stop web.1
Stopping web.1 dyno on ⬢ fpds-scheduler... done
(env) spitfiredd@spitfiredd ~/Documents/schedule $ heroku ps:stop worker.1
Stopping worker.1 dyno on ⬢ fpds-scheduler... done
(env) spitfiredd@spitfiredd ~/Documents/schedule $ heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:Free
(env) spitfiredd@spitfiredd ~/Documents/schedule $ heroku ps:scale worker=1
Scaling dynos... done, now running worker at 1:Free
(env) spitfiredd@spitfiredd ~/Documents/schedule $ heroku ps:scale clock=1
Scaling dynos... !
 ▸    Cannot run more than 2 Free size dynos.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does that have to do with being on the free tier? Will I need to upgrade to hobby?

Comment: In Free tier you can at most run one Dyno for one project. Looks like you are trying to start two dynos 1 Web & 1 Worker. Are you sure you intentionally added a worker dyno?

Comment: I upgrade to the hobby tier and I was able to add all three dynos.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Upgrade from Free to Hobby tier.

Answer (score 0):

get your app name, and get the dyno process number using the following

```
heroku ps
heroku ps:stop run.<the dyno number> --app <the heroku app name>
```

for example

```
heroku ps
heroku ps:stop run.5838 --app afternoon-bayou-10667
```

if the heroku ps:stop doesn't work from the first time, try to do it multiple times.